# Call range argument to execute in python terminal embeded in Vim

Tags: buffers, terminal-buffer

Initial window:

[image: vim opened first,then vert term split the left window]

My expectation: to copy whole or a part of python code in the right window into the left window's python terminal and execute.

My `.vimrc` setting:

```
function! CopyPasteBuffer() 
    normal  gg"*yG
    wincmd p
    call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>pp  :call CopyPasteBuffer()<CR>

function! CopyRun() range
    exe  a:firstline . "," . a:lastline . "y*"
    wincmd p
    call feedkeys("\<C-W>\"*")
endfunction
command! -range PassRange <line1>,<line2>call CopyRun()
nnoremap ,pr :CopyRun<cr>
```

In vim's normal mode in the right window, I type `,pp`  (leader configured as `,`), all python statements in the right pushed into python terminal in the left and executed.

[image]

Now I want to execute a range of python statements in the right, move cursor in the right window and enter into ex mode, and type `1,3pr`, the lines are  executed but not in my desired python terminal such as the above image shows.

How to fix my vimscript?

After following `Maxim Kim`'s suggestion,`1,3PassRange` works, I rewrite the mapping as `nnoremap ,pr :PassRange<cr>`, why can't `1,3pr` get the same effect as `1,3PassRange`?

[image]

Following `Maxim Kim`'s instruction, I want to make more progress, toggle from uppercase to lowercase and from lowercase to uppercase, it is inconvenient.

Without range as argument:

```
nnoremap <leader>pp  :call CopyPasteBuffer()<CR>
```

I can type `,pp` without uppercase to get desired result.
With range as argument:

```
command! -range  Xr <line1>,<line2>call CopyRun()
```

`1,3Xr` can work,i want to make `,1,3re`  map as `1,3Xr` and call `CopyRun`,so add new mapping

```
map <leader>,re :Xr<cr>
```

It can't work, how to fix it?

Comment: I use `:call term_list()[0]->term_sendkeys(getline('.') .. "\<CR>")` to send current line to a terminal window.

Comment: Function using term_sendkeys: https://balki.me/posts/vim-stt/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a vim command that process the range and you actually have it in your code snippet: `PassRange`

So try `:1,3PassRange`

When you do `:1,3pr` you run builtin `print` ex command to print lines in range (See `:h :pr`).

You can't use normal mappings as an ex commands like you tried to do.

Shorten your `:PassRange` command to `:Pr`:

```
 command! -range Pr <line1>,<line2>call CopyRun()
```

And run it with `:1,3Pr`.

Comment: I rewrite the mapping as `nnoremap ,pr :PassRange<cr>`,why `1,3pr` can't get the same effect as `1,3PassRange`?

Comment: @showkey, because mapping is not an ex command. You can't use it like this.

Comment: @showkey rename `PassRange` to `Pr` and use it like `:1,3Pr`

Comment: Please help make a little progress to use all lowercase characters ,i map as `nnoremap ,re :Xr<cr>`,why `1,3re` can't work?

Comment: @showkey you should definitely read about vimscript, mappings, commands somewhere... probably in vim user manual or some book.
You are mixing mappings and user commands. Mappings do not work the same way as user commands. User commands **can not start with lowercase letters**. It is in vim help and user manual.

Comment: I already knew that user commands can not start with lowercase letters,can bypass obstacles?

Comment: @showkey if you knew it is impossible(at least without forking and changing C source code), why do you ask if you can bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

> It can't work, how to fix it?

Everything is working as designed so there is nothing to fix. What you want to do is impossible to achieve with Vim as it currently works. Get over it.

Basically, built-in normal mode commands (like `~` or `w`) and custom normal mode mappings (like your `,p`) can take a positive *count* (`2~`, `4w`, `6,p`, etc.) but not a *range* (like `1,3~` or `5,13,p`). You can't insert an arbitrary range in the middle of a mapping either (like the `,1,3p` you are giving as example). `5,13,p` would be too ambiguous and `,5,13p` is simply not possible.

Now, you *could* work around that limitation by simply creating lots and lots of explicit mappings for every possible range:

```
map <leader>1,2re :<C-u>1,2Xr<cr>
map <leader>1,3re :<C-u>1,3Xr<cr>
map <leader>1,4re :<C-u>1,4Xr<cr>
" etc.
```

This is not very elegant but it will work, in a dumb way, and can be generated in a loop if you want.

Another possibility is using your mapping in visual mode:

```
vjjj,p
```

which should pass the range `<','>` to your custom Ex command `:Xr`.

Another possibility would be to prompt the user for a range via `:help input()` and then feed it to the underlying commands/functions.